# With As Clause Not recognized MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, datagrip

I am trying to use a with as clause in a query.

```
WITH NAME AS 
(
SELECT col1,
       col2
FROM TABLE1
)

SELECT col2, 
       col3
FROM TABLE2
WHERE col2 in (NAME.col1)
```

The query placed in the with as clause works on it's own but I get this error:

> Unknown column NAME.'col1' in 'where clause'

I am more familiar with oracle so this may have caused some error by carrying something over.

Is the order of the clauses wrong and With As comes after where?

Comment: While an answer may exist using `WITH (temp) AS ...`, have you considered using a `JOIN` instead?

Comment: `WHERE col2 IN (SELECT col1 FROM NAME)` ?

Comment: Is this valid syntax for Oracle though?

Comment: You're not referencing the CTE in your top-level query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you do not need the CTE.

```
SELECT col2, 
       col3
FROM TABLE2
WHERE col2 in (SELECT col1 FROM TABLE1)
```

should work

If you want to use CTE (for what reason ever), you have to select from the table

```
WITH NAME AS 
(
SELECT col1,
       col2
FROM TABLE1
)

SELECT col2, 
       col3
FROM TABLE2
WHERE col2 in (select col1 from name)
```